# Google Chrome IETab login pages

Tags: google-chrome, website, login, ietab

I'm using Google Chrome and for certain sites I need to use Internet Explorer. I've installed IE Tab Classic, but I've noticed when pages require an Active Directory popup login, Chrome will prompt me for the username/password first and then switch over to IE.

IE will always show a message indicating that a connection to the page could not be made. I have to then press the "Refresh the page" link and be prompted again for the username/password (this time inside IE); finally the login will work.

Does anyone know why this happens and how I can just login once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do the same, as various of our Intranet sites use NTLM so I use an IE tab for those so that I don't have to provide my domain credentials every time.

I use [IE tab](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd?hl=en-gb) as opposed to [IE tab classic](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/miedgcmlgpmdagojnnbemlkgidepfjfi?hl=en-gb), and for me this too prompts for credentials before switching over to IE.

However, once the switch is made my credentials are successfully passed across automatically, without needing to refresh the IE window or type them in by hand. This means I just dismiss the Chrome login dialog, and I'm logged in to the page I need.

So it may be worth trying out the other extension instead, to see if that helps.

Comment: Ah, thanks. That's quite useful. I have switched back to the IETab plugin. I never thought about just dismissing the chrome credentials box. It's a bit of an inconvenience, but it does the job. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the [Chrome IE Tab Multi](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/fnfnbeppfinmnjnjhedifcfllpcfgeea) extension instead.

> IE Tab Multi is a most similar to original IE,Internet Explorer
>   behavior. You can see IE only site without leaving Chrome and you can
>   run ActiveX controls. this extension supports only Windows. this
>   extension supports Chrome 6 and above.